# Installing MongoDb with Puppet

Tags: puppet

I'm a newbie in Puppet, so maybe you'll find my question a bit stupid...
So, I'm looking for puppet recipe that will install and run Mongodb 2.2 on my machine. By googling I found this module http://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/mongodb But I didn't understand clear what should I do?
It said I have to install module on puppet node first. What does exactly it means? 
Let's say, I have a set of machines those must be configured via puppet.
What do I have to add to puppet recipe to reach this aim?

Comment: possible duplicate of [puppet recipe for MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13384122/puppet-recipe-for-mongodb)

Answer (score 2):

In case someone might be interest on installing the last version of MongoDB this worked very well for me. At the moment of writing the latest stable version is **MongoDB 3.0.3**.

First of all update your OS repositories via the puppet [apt module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apt) (in case you're using a Debian or Ubuntu distribution). Change the data below according to your distribution and version. Check here to get the MongoDB official repositories information: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/install-on-linux/#recommended

```rb
# $::lsbdistcodename should contain what you usually get
# with the `lsb_release -sc` command
$server_lsbdistcodename = downcase($::lsbdistcodename)

apt::source { 'mongodb-org-3.0':
    location    => 'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian',
    release     => "${server_lsbdistcodename}/mongodb-org/3.0",
    repos       => 'main',
    key         => '7F0CEB10',
    key_server  => 'keyserver.ubuntu.com',
    include_src => false
}
```

And then set the `mongodb::globals` class properly to make sure you get **MongoDB 3**. The MongoDB puppet module I'm using is [this one](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/mongodb).

```rb
class { 'mongodb::globals':
    manage_package_repo => false, # disable the 10gen repository
    server_package_name => 'mongodb-org',
    service_name        => 'mongod',
    version             => '3.0.3',
}->
class { '::mongodb::server': }
```

Comment: I believe the more recent `apt::source` uses different key server and include options:
`key => {'id' => '7F0CEB10', 'server' => 'keyserver.ubuntu.com'}, include => {'src' => false}`

Answer (score 1):

Getting mongodb installed with puppet isn't as easy as it seems. It's somewhat difficult to get official Puppet Labs module v0.8.0 to install mongodb 2.6.3. You end up getting an apt error about **mongodb-10gen=2.6.3 not being found**. There's an issue and a patch already but it hasn't been published yet.

So here's what you need to do:

```
git clone https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-mongodb.git
```

Then use the following puppet config:

```
class { '::mongodb::globals':
  manage_package_repo => true,
  server_package_name => 'mongodb-org',
  version => '2.6.3'
}->
class { '::mongodb::server': }
```

This Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running puppet standalone, you will have already installed the puppet gem and have the `puppet` executable. To intall the module, you run `puppet module install puppetlabs/mongodb`. After the module installation, you can simply include the mongodb module in your node definition

```
node 'myhost' {
    include mongodb
}
```

If you want to run a number of nodes that need access to the module, you'll have to setup a puppetmaster and install the node. See [Basic Agent/Master setup][1] for more info.  Make sure that pluginsync=true is enabled in puppet.conf so the module can make it's way to the remote agents.

The puppetmaster will then need a file, normally `site.pp` defined with the nodes it should configure. Finally, include the mongodb module on each node you want to run mongodb and you should be up and running.