# puppet recipe for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, puppet

I'm looking for puppet recipe that will install and run Mongodb 2.2 on my machine. By googling I found this module http://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/mongodb But I didn't understand clear what should I do? It said I have to install module on puppet node first. What does exactly it means? Let's say, I have a set of machines those must be configured via puppet. What do I have to add to puppet recipe to reach this aim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directions are actually pretty clear, I think. You need to install the mongo module in your puppet master's modules directory (as indicated).

Then, in your node definition, add:

```
class mongodb {
  init => 'sysv',
}
```

If that doesn't make sense to you, you should really back up and read the Puppet docs. 
http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/

Comment: hm, I put this code snippet to my base.pp file, but I got error: Syntax error at '=>'; expected '}' at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests/base.pp:4

Answer (score 3):

I was having trouble and came across this question. The syntax that worked for me was:

```
#Class instances are declared like any other resource.
class { 'mongodb' :
    init => 'upstart',
}
```